# How can I make a custom UITableView refresh control?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I know how to add a refresh control to a `UITableView` but how can I make a custom one using my own image and animation?

Comment: Google turns up a number of good tutorials: Here's one that has been updated with Swift code examples: http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple google search will lead you to many tutorials on how to do this:
Such as: [link](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-add-a-custom-pull-to-refresh-in-your-ios-application/)

The main just in it involves making an object listen for scrollview delegate events, adjusting the scrollview insets when in refresh mode to pull the scrollview down, and animating the view until it's told to reset itself and the insets appropriately.

Comment: The original poster was asking how to implement this in Swift.